How can we attract more professionals?
I think one issue with crypto SE now is it has not attracted many professionals e.g. academics etc from field of cryptography. What can be done to remedy this situation?

We have quite some professionals here. A short list of people I suspect (/know) to be professionals in the field of crypto: poncho, maarten, fgrieu, the bear, Samuel, Gilles, Dmitry, Yehuda, Chris, zooko, jww, bristol. This list may be lacking.

@SEJPM Let them be even more i welcome that

IMHO, it is required to have better statements of questions, self-contained without linking to a paper. Too many of the questions here are of the form "why is eq 7 of ppr 9 correct?" or "why do scheme_X for goal_Y?", of course the second is preferable to the first.

@SEJPM I'm not a crypto professional (as in, someone who's done research in the field), I'm merely a crypto implementer, and not even at the extreme edge of side channel resistance requirements. But there are others in your list who are or have been academics in the field. While more is always better, I don't think this site lacks professionals.

Many of the IACR crypto conferences (Crypto, Asiacrypt, Eurocrypt, etc). We should put together a slide deck (using some of the stuff from our upcoming design) and include a Best of and Worst of list of questions and answers, some of our memes, etc. Then try to get a member of the community who is presenting at the conference to share.

this is going to be difficult, as we seem to traditionally have had problems in organizing community efforts (which this would be?)...

Maybe I'll crowdfund a trip :)

academics should be glad to know site such as CSE exists

Having someone there from us would be great, but it seems to me like a strong commitment. I think that, at least, we could make some flyers that could be distributed during registration, as some related conferences/workshops do.

BTW, just adding to mikeazo's idea, I think a presentation during the rump session of major conferences, could be a great place to advertise the site.

@cygnusv Yep you should because crypto is academic discipline and not place for amateurs
